# How to customizing django.contrib.auth.views.login form

Tags: django, django-forms

My url is

```
`url(r'^login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),`
```

In my login.html template I'm using

```
  <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>
      <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
      {{ form.username }}
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
      {{ form.password }}
    </p>
    {% if next %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    {% else %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
  </form>
```

Now I want use placeholder instead of label. How can I do this. and also want a customize look and feels with bootstrap. Please help how can I do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.username }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.password }}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can edit the placeholder with django form:

```
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username', 'class': 'form-input'}))
```

And then use css to apply the style:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#f00; }
::-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; }
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. Actually I want placeholder with django form as you suggested but as I didn't write any views and can't understand where I use those form code in django. I know generally I do a models.py then a form.py and use those form in views.py but as there is no views and I'm stuck how can I use forms in in forms.py and where to put that forms.py file. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done in template using django package widget_tweaks.

So your code looks like:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    {% render_field form.username placeholder="<your text>" %}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {% render_field form.password placeholder="<your text>" %}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

For more refer the page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks